# form is not valid to django why

Tags: python, django, authentication

the model:

```
    class authentifier(models.Model):
    matricule =models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    nom =models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    prenom=models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    statut = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
```

the code forms.py for authentification :

```
     from django import forms
     class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
     print(666)
     matricule =  forms.CharField(required=True , widget=forms.TextInput)
     password = forms.CharField(required=True , widget= forms.PasswordInput)
```

template html :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial- 
     scales=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

       </head>
      <body>
           <form>
        <form method="POST">
    {%  csrf_token %}
   <tr><th><label for="id_matricule">Matricule:</label></th><td><input 
  type="text" name="matricule"  id="Matricule"></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input 
      type="password" name="password"  id="password"></td></tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Se Connecter">

          </form>


            </body>


                  </html>
```

I found that form.is_valid() = false - but i have no idea how to get the reason WHY...

i need to do authentification with matricule and password

Comment: where's the view code? also why do have 2 <form> tags in your HTML? And why don't you use the form rendering tools provided by Django (e.g. `{{ form.as_p }}`) instead of manually typing all the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `{{ form.errors }}` to the template, then Django will tell you exactly why the form is not valid.